# NPM ssl certificate issue

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, ssl-certificate, artifactory

Currently we need to ignore the strict-ssl false configuration from our .npmrc file in order to have secure connection to our private npm registry hosted in JFrog Artifactory.

I tried pointing the cert.pem file by using `npm config set cafile <full path to cert.pem>` and also
`export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<full path to cert.pem>` both does not work.

I'm using Node.js 12.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="path to yourrootcertificate.pem or yourrootcertificate.cer>"
```

or

```
npm config set cafile "path toyourrootcertificate.pem or yourrootcertificate.cer"
```